# data insertion into hive table

Tags: hadoop, hive

I want to insert data into hive table.

1) create database.

2) create table in particular database.

3) create a dummy table in particular position.

4)Using dummy table insert data into main table.

when i insert data process complete without exception but data not insert in table.

```
hive> create database final;
```

OK
Time taken: 2.56 seconds

```
hive> create table final.abc (user_name string, password string)
> ROW FORMAT DELIMITED   
> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
> LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
> STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

OK
Time taken: 0.591 seconds

```
hive> create table foo (user string , password string)          
> ROW FORMAT DELIMITED   
> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
> LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
> STORED AS TEXTFILE
> Location '/usr/hive/hive-0.10.0/fiels';
```

OK
Time taken: 0.051 seconds

```
hive> insert into table final.abc select 'username','password' from foo;

Total MapReduce jobs = 3
Launching Job 1 out of 3
Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
Starting Job = job_201306191046_0002, Tracking URL =/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201306191046_0002
Kill Command = /usr/hadoop/hadoop-1.1.2/libexec/../bin/hadoop job  -kill job_201306191046_0002
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 0; number of reducers: 0
2013-06-19 12:04:36,870 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2013-06-19 12:04:37,878 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%
Ended Job = job_201306191046_0002
Ended Job = -331805541, job is filtered out (removed at runtime).
Ended Job = -1750065493, job is filtered out (removed at runtime).
Moving data to: hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/hive-root/hive_2013-06-19_12-04-32_830_4819535129373917658/-ext-10000
Loading data to table final.abc
Table final.abc stats: [num_partitions: 0, num_files: 0, num_rows: 0, total_size: 0, raw_data_size: 0]

MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Job 0:  HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 SUCCESS
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec
OK
Time taken: 5.475 seconds
```

**If any idea please suggest me. where am i wrong.**

Comment: you should have some data in dummy table atleast one row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 'username','password' from foo
```

The above command should display atleast one row then only it can insert data into new table.

so upload some sample data file to `/usr/hive/hive-0.10.0/fiels` so that your query works.

create sample file with data like below

```
username,password
```

upload that file to hadoop cluster

```
hadoop fs -put filename /usr/hive/hive-0.10.0/fiels
```

Comment: in files folder any txt file ar same name ?

Comment: any file under that folder will be taken as input

Comment: now i have a text file in files folder. than i follow the same procedure but get also 0 rows update.

Comment: first test select 'username','password' from foo  if it gives any data then only data can be inserted